# Simple: Can HTML5 Play a .mpd Manifest File Through Its Video Tag?

Tags: streaming, transcoding, mpeg-dash

I have a Movie_Manifest.mpd file that is made up of 5 .webm video streams (consisting of different sizes and bps) and 1 audio file. The question I'm asking is: can it be played through a "simple" HTML5 video tag?

I've tried this and it doesn't work:

```
<video controls>
  <source src = "Movie_Manifest.mpd"/>
</video>
```

Well it works, but it chooses the lowest quality video stream and the output is laggy. I would like it to have adaptive bit streaming. You might think, "Do you think your bandwidth is just *that* slow?" Yeah, my bandwidth is slow, but not *that* slow. And besides, when I run that low quality webm file on its own, it runs smooth.

So to reiterate:

1) Can I use a "simple" HTML5 video tag for adaptive bit streaming?

Or

2) Do I have to use an open source media player (that the video tag would be accessing through a javascript)?

Thanks and happy streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all browsers and mobile devices natively support MPEG-DASH ( .mpd), DASH is natively supported in Chrome (including Android 4.0+), Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1, and many SmartTVs.

To answer your questions:

1) To ensure that your encoded video can stream in all environments, make sure to embed relevant client players in your application, you can find more information about Adaptive bitrate streaming here - http://cloudinary.com/documentation/video_manipulation_and_delivery#adaptive_bitrate_streaming_hls_and_mpeg_dash

2) Here is a list of open source [HTML5 video players](http://cloudinary.com/blog/html5_video_player).

Answer (score 1):

no. video tag can not play mpd, and will not do adaptative bitrate. You must write that yourself, or use a free, or commercial implementation